# How to find maximum length of a given character in series from substring in python?

Tags: python

The string just include with "`.`" and "`x`" e.x.: "`..xxx..x.x.xxxxx.xx`".
I just want to take longest substring contain "`x`" characters from above string to return 5!

Comment: what have you tried so far? show your code and the problem you face for us to help you.

Comment: s"x.x.xxxx..x..xxxxxx...xxx" lets say string like this and b=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```py
s = "..xxx..x.x.xxxxx.xx"
start = 0
maxcount = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    # Using != "x" can work for strings which include other characters besides "."
    if s[i] != "x":
        # reset the start position
        start = i
        continue
    # update the result only if it is larger than current result
    if i - start > maxcount:
        maxcount = i - start
print(maxcount) # Output: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = "..xxx..x.x.xxxxx.xx"
count = []
c = 0
for i in t:
    if i == "x":
        c += 1
    if i == ".":
        count.append(c)
        c = 0

print(max(count))
```

Refer to this